# transparent hover background

Tags: html, css, hover

Please visit the 'jsfiddle' [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/on4562Lu/6/), where the output can be seen. When hover displays the menu text, the background of the text field is transpernt + and lower zindex. I haven't set any transparency or zindex to the menu.
I have tried every possible technique to get it resolved but no luck.

```
    .control-menu {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    height: 380px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    z-index: 100;
}
.control-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.btn {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 15px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-right: 1px groove #f00;
    text-shadow: #666666 1px 1px 1px;
}
.btn-name {
    display: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    padding-top: 16px !important;
}
.btn:hover .btn-name {
    display:inline;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 17px 20px 12px 0;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-right: 1px groove #f00;
}
.btn.active {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
}
.btn.active:hover .btn-name {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

[image: Output Image]

can someone please guide solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add

```
 z-index:200
```

to the .btn, didn't change any positioning [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/on4562Lu/8/)

Answer (score 1):

just add **position: relative;** and  **z-index: 1000;**

`.btn:hover .btn-name {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #e0e0e0 !important;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 17px 20px 12px 0;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-right: 1px groove #f00;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
 }`

Answer (score 1):

in the `btn:hover .btn-name` add `position relative and z-index: 1`

.btn:hover .btn-name {

```
    /* add this */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;

    /* you code   */
    display: inline;
    background-color: #e0e0e0 !important;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 17px 20px 12px 0;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-right: 1px groove #f00;
```

}

here the fix : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccdiego5/on4562Lu/7/)